# How to stop Language translation Api from translating form flow input in bot framework

Tags: c#, botframework

```
    Code:
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
            {
                //trust Webchat &SMS channel
                MicrosoftAppCredentials.TrustServiceUrl(@"https://webchat.botframework.com", DateTime.MaxValue);
                MicrosoftAppCredentials.TrustServiceUrl(@"https://sms.botframework.com", DateTime.MaxValue);

                Trace.TraceInformation($"Incoming Activity is {activity.ToJson()}");

                if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(activity.Text))
                    {

                        //detect language of input text
                        var userLanguage = TranslationHandler.DetectLanguage(activity);

                        //save user's LanguageCode to Azure Table Storage
                        var message = activity as IMessageActivity;

                        try
                        {
                            using (var scope = DialogModule.BeginLifetimeScope(Conversation.Container, message))
                            {
                                var botDataStore = scope.Resolve<IBotDataStore<BotData>>();
                                var key = new AddressKey()
                                {
                                    BotId = message.Recipient.Id,
                                    ChannelId = message.ChannelId,
                                    UserId = message.From.Id,
                                    ConversationId = message.Conversation.Id,
                                    ServiceUrl = message.ServiceUrl
                                };
                                var userData = await botDataStore.LoadAsync(key, BotStoreType.BotUserData, CancellationToken.None);
                                var storedLanguageCode = userData.GetProperty<string>(StringConstants.UserLanguageKey);
                                //update user's language in Azure Table Storage

                                if (storedLanguageCode != userLanguage)
                                {
                                    userData.SetProperty(StringConstants.UserLanguageKey, userLanguage);
                                    await botDataStore.SaveAsync(key, BotStoreType.BotUserData, userData, CancellationToken.None);
                                    await botDataStore.FlushAsync(key, CancellationToken.None);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            throw ex;
                        }
                        //translate activity.Text to English before sending to LUIS for intent
                        activity.Text = TranslationHandler.TranslateTextToDefaultLanguage(activity, userLanguage);
                        //await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new Dialogs.RootDialog());
                        await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, MakeRoot);
                    }
                    else {
                        await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, MakeRoot);

                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    HandleSystemMessageAsync(activity);
                }
                var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
                return response;
            }
            internal static IDialog<object> MakeRoot()
            {
                try
                {
                    return Chain.From(() => new RootDialog());
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
            }
```

I am implementing Microsoft language translator in Bot framework and also implementing the Language understanding Service(Luis). In my code, once a user sends in a message to the bot, the language translator first detect the user language before sending it to LUIS (my LUIS application is in English) in the root dialog, then the bot translate the response back to the user language using the state data.

Everything was working fine until i made use of the formflow, some input text by the bot user in the form flow are being translated to some other languages if they are not English words. Please how do i correct this without removing the Language Translation API?.

note:
There is a section in my RootDailog that calls the formflow. Is there anyway i can stop the language translator API from translation the form input?

Comment: Please share the code where you are using the translator api, as well as how your FormFlow dialog is being used.  (It is possible to tell which dialog is on the stack, and determine whether or not to call the translate api accordingly.  But, without your code it is impossible to determine how this should be done.)

Comment: i have added code from my message controller for better explanation

Answer (score 1):

You can inspect the dialog stack and not translate if the last dialog in the stack is the FormFlow dialog.  Something like:

```
bool translate = true;
using (var scope = DialogModule.BeginLifetimeScope(Conversation.Container, activity))
{
    var botData = scope.Resolve<IBotData>();
    await botData.LoadAsync(default(CancellationToken));

    var stack = scope.Resolve<IDialogTask>();
    if (stack.Frames != null && stack.Frames.Count > 0)
    {
        var lastFrame = stack.Frames[stack.Frames.Count - 1];
        var frameValue = lastFrame.Target.GetType().GetFields()[0].GetValue(lastFrame.Target);
        if (frameValue.GetType() == typeof(FormDialog<SandwichOrder>))
        {
            //in the FormFlow dialog ... do NOT translate
            translate = false;
        }
    }
}
if (translate)
{
    //translate activity.Text to English before sending to LUIS for intent
    activity.Text = TranslationHandler.TranslateTextToDefaultLanguage(activity, userLanguage);
}
await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, MakeRoot);
```